# There would be/will be/might be

Tags: modal-verbs, usage, dummy-pronouns

I'm using these constructions without any confidence. I don't know wheater they are correct or not, in case where I try to build up the whole sentence with them.

These constructions are:

> 1. There **would be**
> 2. There **will be**
> 3. There **might be**

I've just used them in these sentences below:

> 1. There **would be** a big house in this city if we had money.
> 2. There **would be** a problem to go abroad for employment without qualification.
> 3. There **will be** a biggest statue on the middle of this city.
> 4. There **might be** a poisonous snack in this forest.

Is it the correct way to use these constructions in the context of the whole sentence?

Should I use them in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Would/Will/Might

> 1. There would be

Is used after an assumption, like you did in your first sentence. *Under these circumstances, there **would** be XXX*. If the circumstances are met, then the event in the second clause would happen for sure.

> 2. There will be might be

Isn't grammatically correct in the slightest. I guess you meant **There will be** alone, which simply is the future of **there is**, to describe something in the future.

> 3. There might be

Is an incertitude. You basically convey the fact that you're not sure about something. Can, Could and Must cant also be used for that, with different degrees of intensity. Please see: [Can/Could/May/Might/Must](http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs-can-could-may-might-must.aspx).

### About your sentences

1. and 4 are indubitably correct usages of *would* and *might*.
   Same for 3., correct use of *will*, if you're pretty sure (or convinced) the statue will be there (but it's just *big*, not *biggest*, and ***in*** the middle).
2. puzzles me. I would have said *There **might** be a problem to go abroad [...]*, but I could see *would* being used as meaning:

> If you went abroad for employment without qualification, there would be a problem.